# Как правильно вынести метод из flatMap?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, lambda

Добрый день есть функция `rxJava`  и есть метод `flatMap`:

```
@Override
public Observable<AuthorizationEntity> confirmVerificationCode(String email,int verificationCode) {
    return restClient.getVerificationApi(email,verificationCode)
            .flatMap((Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<AuthorizationEntity>>) responseBodyResponse -> {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                AuthorizationEntity authorizationEntity = gson.fromJson(responseBodyResponse.body().string(), AuthorizationEntity.class);
                authorizationEntity.setToken(responseBodyResponse.headers().get("MPOS_AUTH_TOKEN"));
                return Observable.fromArray(authorizationEntity);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

как из этого `flatMap` вынесни ламбда в отдельный метод и использовать конструкцию вида `this::method`?

Comment: Хоть убей не понимаю, что не так в вопросе и за что минусуют

Comment: @Chubatiy ))) дети играются наверно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все очень просто:

1. выносите лямбду в отдельный метод с соотвествующей сигнатурой

   ```
   private static Observable<AuthorizationEntity> parse(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse)
   ```
2. в местах, где использовалась лямбда, пишите следующее:

   ```
   .flatMap(MySuperClass::parse)
   ```

ps если в сигнатуре убрать `static`, то обращение к методу будет происходить через `this`, и вызов соответственно будет выглядеть так:

```
.flatMap(this::parse)
```